# Same SQL query performed in different times

Tags: sql, caching, sql-server-2012, timeout

I am trying to run a simple select statement and each time I run it it takes a different amount of time to complete.

The first time takes 0 seconds, the second time it takes 3 seconds and the third time it takes 10 seconds. And if run again the query will start from 0,3,10 and keeps going on.

Why is this happening? It seems there is some kind of logic behind it.

This is causing the service that uses the database to timeout.This query is run by a specific software for thousands of times.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACT_CONTACT WITH (NOLOCK)  WHERE    MKEY ='XXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

I am using SQL Server 2012. The db contains 369 tables. The table CONTACT_CONTACT contains 62497 records.

Comment: What query? What is the database like? There is not enough information to give any kind of answer.

Comment: SQL Server 2012. Query is a simple select statement.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen what information do you need?

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache and buffers every time you run your SQL query? If not, please try this first and measure the execution time. Also, try to include actual execution plan `(Ctrl + M in SSMS)` and check whether it is same every time you execute. `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS SELECT * FROM CONTACT_CONTACT WITH (NOLOCK)  WHERE    MKEY ='XXXXXXXXXXXX'`